# TSQL rolling schedule (NOT SUM)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to calculate a Rolling Schedule State Date for different resources.

```
Use AdventureWorks2012;
IF OBJECT_ID('TempTable1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE TempTable1
SELECT SOH.SalesPersonID, SOD.ProductId as ResourceID,
        SOH.DueDate as DueDate,
        SOD.OrderQty as DayIncrement,
        DATEADD(Day, SOD.OrderQty, SOH.DueDate) as SchedStartDate,
--
--  What I actually want for SchedStart date is 
--  DATEADD(Day, SOD.OrderQty, SOH.DueDate)       FOR THE FIRST RECORD of a Resource ID
--  Then That Date + DayIncrement for subsequent Records
--  
-- The first Three Records for 707 should be 
--      2005-08-14
--      2005-08-18
--      2005-08-28
--
        Row_Number() over (PARTITION BY SOD.ProductID ORDER By SOH.DueDate) as JResourceNumber
    INTO TempTable1
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
        INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
            ON SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
    WHERE SOH.SalesPersonID <= 274 and 
        SOD.ProductId < 710
    ORDER by ResourceID, DueDate

Select * from TempTable1
```

---

```
SalesPersonID   ResourceID  DueDate                 DayIncrement    SchedStartDate            JResourceNumber
274               707      2005-08-13 00:00:00.000       1          2005-08-14 00:00:00.000           1
274               707      2006-06-13 00:00:00.000       4          2006-06-17 00:00:00.000           2
274               707      2006-08-13 00:00:00.000       10         2006-08-23 00:00:00.000           3
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly you want this:

Please note that I have used AdventureWorks2014 as I don't have 2012.

```
    Use AdventureWorks2014;

IF OBJECT_ID('TempTable1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE TempTable1


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempRollingSched') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempRollingSched
SELECT  SOD.ProductId,
        RolingSched=MIN(SOH.DueDate)  
        INTO   #TempRollingSched
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
        INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
            ON SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
    WHERE SOH.SalesPersonID <= 274 and 
        SOD.ProductId < 710  
        GROUP BY SOD.ProductId

SELECT #TempRollingSched.ProductId, #TempRollingSched.RolingSched FROM #TempRollingSched


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempRollingSchedComplete') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempRollingSchedComplete
SELECT SOH.SalesPersonID, SOD.ProductId as ResourceID,
        SOH.DueDate as DueDate,
        SOD.OrderQty as DayIncrement,
        TRS.RolingSched,
--
--  What I actually want for SchedStart date is 
--  DATEADD(Day, SOD.OrderQty, SOH.DueDate)       FOR THE FIRST RECORD of a Resource ID
--  Then That Date + DayIncrement for subsequent Records
--  
-- The first Three Records for 707 should be 
--      2005-08-14
--      2005-08-18
--      2005-08-28
--
        Row_Number() over (PARTITION BY SOD.ProductID ORDER By SOH.DueDate) as JResourceNumber 
    INTO TempTable1


    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
        INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
            ON SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
            INNER JOIN #TempRollingSched AS TRS ON TRS.ProductID=SOD.ProductID
    WHERE SOH.SalesPersonID <= 274 and 
        SOD.ProductId < 710
    ORDER by ResourceID, DueDate

Select  A.SalesPersonID, 
        A.ResourceID, 
        A.DueDate, 
        A.DayIncrement, 
        SchedStartDate=DATEADD(Day, (SUM(DayIncrement ) OVER  (PARTITION BY  ResourceID ORDER By  JResourceNumber)), RolingSched),  
        A.JResourceNumber   from TempTable1 AS A
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: THANK you for your quick response.  Sorry to say, not quit what I'm looking for ... (understanding you are using AW2014).  First three records should be: 2011-07-14  (Correct) ... 2011-07-18 (2011-07-14 Plus DayIncrement) ...  and then 2011-07-28 (New date from record two DayIncrement of 10).  One of the givaways that it's not quit what I'm looking for is that the schedule date should NEVER be less withing the ResourceId.  Thanks again for the response.

Comment: ... also, as I'm new - if you have a minute to point to instructions on uploading results - it would be MUCH appreciated.  ... and, I know how to spell GAVA and THAT'S ABOUT IT ;-)

Comment: @JackB should the first three dates be  2011-07-14 00:00:00.000
2011-07-18 00:00:00.000
2011-07-28 00:00:00.000 , respectively or they should be 2011-07-14 00:00:00.000
2012-05-17 00:00:00.000
2012-07-27 00:00:00.000 when using AW2014

Comment: That looks GREAT - THANK YOU .... and thank you for NOT sleeping.  Apparently I'm too new (ie low "Reputation") to even acknowledge the correct answer.

Comment: @JackB no worries glad it worked for you. Its strange I thought you could upvote or select correct answers with any reputation.

Comment: OK, looking at the results, I'm confussed - works GREAT through record 5.  BUT record 6 should be 2011-08-24 (2011-08-19 + 5)?  The SUM() function then return to correct at the following record.  I added a column for the running total ( SUM(SOD.OrderQty ) OVER  (PARTITION BY SOD.ProductID ORDER By SOH.DueDate) as DaysToAdd) and this also shows the error for records 11, 20, 25 and ResourceID 709 at record 28 starts bad.

Comment: @JackB yeah you're right it didn't look right. See my latest edit. This should do it.

Comment: @JackB should have done PARTITION BY  ResourceID ORDER By  JResourceNumber rather than PARTITION BY  ResourceID ORDER By  DueDate as the field DueDate some times has the same date repeated and hence we got the funny results.